# Laravel global scope with relations

Tags: php, laravel, scope, relationship

I'd like to have a model with a global query scope that scopes on a polymorphic one to one relationship.

The thing is that everything is working and I can create the global query scope but I do not get the relationship in the `apply` function in the global query scope class. I'd like to make the query with the relationship instead of just making a join query or something else.

Does anyone know if thats possible?

I have the following code:

```
class Content extends Model {
    use Environmentabletrait;
}

trait EnvironmentableTrait {
    public static function bootEnvironmentableTrait() {
        static::addGlobalScope(new EnvironmentScope);
    }

    public function environment() {
        return $this->morphOne(Environment::class, 'environmentable');
    }
}

class Environment extends Model {
    public function environmentable() {
        return $this->morphTo();
    }
}

class EnvironmentScope implements ScopeInterface {
    public function apply(Builder $builder, Model $model) {
        $builder-> ...
    }
}
```

And

I hope I've explained it well enough;)

Many thanks in advance

Comment: Hello , is that possible that we can also do inner join between two table here in Model??

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Never mind, I've fixed it with the following code:

```
public function apply(Builder $builder, Model $model)
{
    return $builder->whereHas('environment', function ($query) {
        $query->where('environment', app()->environment());
    });
}
```